# Headphone no sound in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, headphones

It worked fine for two years, but the Windows 7 on my laptop no longer plays sound through headphones.  When plugged in, the speakers stop (I've read that some people's speakers play instead of headphones, but not the case with mine).  Everything works fine on my Ubuntu partition of the same laptop.

Here are pictures of the "Sound" window

headphones not plugged in:

[image]

plugged in:

[image]

Comment: I don't know the reason behind this issue but I noticed that whenever my headphones/speakers were muted in Linux(Ubuntu) at the time of shutdown, I couldn't get any sound when booted into Windows. In order to get sound from headphone, I have to reboot into Linux, increase the volume of headphones (plugged in), boot into Windows, and they works fine. Perhaps, someone can explain the reason for this issue here.

Answer (score 0):

try this out..

Speaker or headphone can be set as default.... [I'm nt sure if both can be activated in Win 7 at the same time ]

Control Panel -> Hardware & sounds -> Sound ->

In Playback tab Select Speaker / Headphone and click the drop-down Select Default.....

U can now enjoy hearing n headphone.. 
hope this helps...

if this will not working then u re-install your audio driver and install a genuine audio driver

Comment: Do you know the reason why it happens? The issue occurs many times in my system with Windows+Linux installed.

Comment: I did this, no change.