# Headphones work using Linux, not Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a computer and two partitions: Debian and Windows 7. The thing is I can hear sounds through my connected headphones on Linux and can't when I am on Windows.

Provided that:

- I have installed the audio card drivers;
- I have attempted to uninstall the hardware and install the drivers all over again;
- the volume is up;

what could be the issue? How do I get more information on what's going on in my system?

Comment: A similar issue was discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/891803/headphone-no-sound-in-windows-7/891812#comment1192830_891812) but wasn't answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the speaker icon in the taskbar and go to Playback Devices. There you highlight your Headphone port and set it as Default. If Default is greyd out, That means it is already Default.

Then double click on that port and check the Levels.

[image]

Comment: I've been caught out by this as well. On some systems you need to plug in your headphones for the headphone device to turn up.